# Two kinds of authentication in same ASP.NET webapp

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication

If I have an MVC/WebAPI webapp and wish to have some endpoints authenticated as if a real user was accessing them, and some endpoints using a different flow (i.e. with client ID/secret because an automated client application running on a schedule needed to access them), what's the basic technique for that?

Since most examples seem to be about one or the other, the solutions revolve around implementing auth into the pipeline, and adding the `AuthorizeAttribute` to the relevant endpoints.

I suspect the solution involves subclassing `AuthorizeAttribute` in two different ways and applying the relevant one to the right endpoints, but the packages made available for auth (e.g. Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt) is just hooked into the pipeline and I don't see how to make the actual auth behaviour itself change.

Comment: Sounds like role-based authorization is what you're looking for. By giving appropriate roles to the client application you can filter out anyone who is authenticated but doesn't have the necessary roles/claims.

Comment: No it's auth methods I'm working on. Like the difference between a user authenticating with username/password, or an application authenticating user client ID and secret. Once authenticated, whatever identity it is can then be attributed roles.

Comment: Ah, I believe the AuthorizeAttribute just enforces authorization. It sounds like you may need a separate API endpoint to deal with issuing access tokens that packages like Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt can read and populate the "user's" claims. Your application shouldn't really need to know whether it's a regular user or application, just that the request is made with the appropriate roles/claims.

Comment: This is certainly possible. Is this the old ASP.NET running on .NET Framework? Or is it ASP.NET Core running on some version of .NET Core or .NET 5+?